# Use paging in facebook api

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to fetch the list of friends. The sample code with IOS facebook SDK gives all the friends i currently have but when i try to fetch list manually using graph api . I get only a few. Then i read under permissions "This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request." My questions is
1. how come sample IOS facebook code can fetch all the friends and when i make graph api call i get only few. The call i am using "me/friends" ?.

1. Will it be possible to get friends ids or emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 4/30/2014, you can only access the friends who also use the app, and you have to explicitly ask for the user_friends permission to even get that.